# Flex/MXML - Restricting input field from getting an input starting with Zero

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

I've searched across SO, but couldn't able to find anything relevant my requirement.

Basically, I would like to restrict a `textinput` field from getting any input starting/prefixed with 0 (although 0 can be suffixed).

I knew that we can use the `restrict` property to do the restriction, and I'm finding it difficult to get a mxml relevant regular expression to handle this.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you get the text field and do a conditional where if the charCode(0) is zero?
Pure AS would look something like this.

```
    var tf:TextField = new TextField();

    public function Main() 
    {
        tf.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onkeydown);
        addChild(tf);
    }


    private function onkeydown(e:Event):void 
    {
        if (tf.text.charAt(0) == "0")
        {
            //Create an alert, snip the text field, cause a stackovereflow.
            //Maybe hack the computer for bitcoins just because.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks quantomworks!.. However I'm looking for a pure `regexp` solution which should be done through the `restrict` property. Any thoughts?

Comment: `restrict` doesn't work with regex - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#restrict

Comment: @PetrHrehorovsky Thanks for headsup!